# How to stop summing a harmonic series when it reaches a specified target in Java?

Tags: java, loops, math, series

I'm a complete beginner in Java who just recently got introduced to loops. I'm trying to do write a program that reads in a target and finds the first n such that 1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + ... + 1/n > target. The problem supplied a code with the initialization of n and sum missing as well as the condition of while and its statements missing.

I'm able to work out how to make the harmonic series loop, but I'm not sure what to set n with to stop the loop when it exceeds the target.We've not learned about arrays in class yet..

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 This program computes how many steps the sum 1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + ...
 needs to exceed a given target. 
 */
public class ReciprocalSum
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {  

        double sum = 0;
        int n = ????  ;

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Target: ");
        double target = in.nextDouble();
        int i = 0; 

//Notes 
        // 1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/4 + ..... 1/n 
        //Make a loop that repeats itself starting with n = 1 --> 1/1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/4 + 1/n 

        // 1.0/n + (1.0/ n - 1) + (1.0/n-2) +.... if n =4 --> 1/4 + 1/3 + 1/2 + 1/1 as long as n >0 


        while ( n > 0) 
        {  
            sum += 1.0/n ;
            n--; 
        }

        System.out.println("n: " + n);
        System.out.println("sum: " + sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: The answer is in the question: *starting with n = 1* Not sure while your loop decrements n at each iteration rather than incrementing it.

Comment: Thank you for your hint, I think I started off in the wrong direction...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`n` should be incremented in the loop (and therefore it should start at `0`), and the loop should be exited when you reach the target:

```
int n = 0;

...

while (sum <= target) 
{  
    n++;
    sum += 1.0/n;
}
```

Comment: This code makes absolute sense to me but for some reason it produces the wrong sum for me. Ex: target: 1.5  n: 3
sum: 1.5 when sum is supposed to be
sum: 1.8333333333333333.

Comment: @Vickie In that case, change the condition to `sum <= target`

Comment: That makes n off by 1. I tried adding an extra line outside the loop saying sum += 1.0/n; which worked for the above example, but caused n and sum to be off by 1 for other examples. So I'm quite lost..

Comment: @Vickie It seems you want `n` to contain the index of the last term added. In that case, initialize it to 0 and increment it before adding to the sum.

Comment: Thank you. This works when the sum <= target and when n is initialized as 0  is incremented before adding it to the sum.

Answer (score 2):

Because Java 8+ has lambdas, and you can generate a range `1` to `n` and perform your calculation and get the sum in one step. Basically, you could do

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Target: ");
double target = in.nextDouble(), sum = 1.0;
int n = 1;
while (sum < target) {
    sum = IntStream.range(1, n).mapToDouble(i -> 1.0 / i).sum();
    n++;
}
System.out.printf("n=%d, sum=%.2f%n", n, sum);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that in this way by calculating `sum` of the series until its sum bigger than the target value:

```
double sum = 0;
int n = 1;
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Target: ");
double target = in.nextDouble();  
while(sum <= target){
      sum = sum + 1.0/n;
      n = n + 1;
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

Comment: This code causes the sum to be off by + 1/n. I figured out that the problem lies in that the loop exits when sum  = target  but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: you can change the condition of while loop to `sum <= target`

in this way it will work fine even if the ` target = sum` at some cases